# Where to serialize and normalize the json data in an asp.net react app: On the client-site or server-side?

Tags: asp.net, reactjs, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, json.net

I am working on an asp.net react application. So far, I have done the serialization and normalization of the nested data on the client-side using `normalizr`. I wonder if I should better perform these tasks within `ASP.NET Web API` using `json.NET`.

I wonder what is the common practice when developing asp.net react applications. Which one is more preferable? Or, would this be a subjective choice?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest moving, whatever processing you can, to client side as this would take unnecessary load off from server and would improve your server performance.

Also you would expect your server side apis to receive objects rather than a string which would then be parsed and serialized. Not clean too i think.